# How to set extended properties of the forwarded message using EWS API?

Tags: api, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS api and I whant to forward email message with addition internet headers.

This is how I forward email message:

```
// emilMsg is of type EmailMessage
ResponseMessage forwardMsg = emailMsg.createForward();
forwardMsg.send();
```

The main problem that "**createForward**" returns object of type *ResponseMessage*. I know how to add extended properties in *EmailMessage*, but what about *ResponseMessage*?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, first save ResponseMessage that would give you an EmailMessage, then set extendedProperties in that :-)

Something like this ::

```
    emailMessage = responseMessage.save();

    UUID yourPropertySetId = UUID.fromString("01638372-9F96-43b2-A403-B504ED14A910");

    ExtendedPropertyDefinition propertyDefinitionBase = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition( yourPropertySetId,
                        "MyProperty",
                        MapiPropertyType.String);

    emailMessage.setExtendedProperty( propertyDefinitionBase, "MyValue" );

    emailMessage.send();
```